# How would Slavs call a bear if they didn't use euphemism?

Tags: proto-indo-european, slavic-languages

Unlike Latin "ursus" or English "bear", the Slavic word "medved" is not cognate to the reconstructed PIE "*Hrtkos". It is believed that this word is a Slavic euphemism meaning "honey-eater". I am interested, however, what would happen if Slavs didn't use it, but still retained all the sound laws that shaped the Slavic languages. Can we try to reconstruct this word in Proto-Slavic?

Comment: There's a [similar question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/7828/1236) on Russian Language SE, I reconstructed that word for the Common Slavic, Old Church Slavonic and Modern Russian. [My answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/7831/1236) is in Russian followed by an English translation.

Comment: Actually, the English "bear" is also not a cognate to the reconstructed PIE "*Hrtkos", it is derived from Proto-Germanic *beron, literally "the brown (one)", and it's also euphemism.

Comment: Euphemism or periphrasis?

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE - Euphemism. The bear is the biggest carnivorous animal, in the North of Europe it was considered a kind of totem, and its name was taboo, that's why the Germanic, Baltic, and Slavic languages didn't retain the original word, but substituted it with euphemisms: 'brown' with Germans, 'licker' with Balts, and 'honey-eater' with Slavs.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE The original PIE etymon appears to have meant something like "destroyer".

Comment: med in 'medved' from 'madhu' or honey which is even used in Sanskrit. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, the question is, which tribes are to be defined as 'Ancient Slavs'. In other words, into which depths of hystorical abyss we are to enter.

The meaning would be more like 'honey-knower', not 'honey-eater', because the Southern form of this word was ***ведмедь*** (and ***ведмід*** in more archaic Ukranian) and therefore in speakers' minds the structuring went most  likely as ***мёд + вед***.

Such a parsing is also confirmed by the Komi belives, whose language and culture preserved a lot from ancient Slavic times, seeing bears as spirits with a knowledge of wealth (the honey, alongside with furs, being one of the forms of ancient 'currency') and solar deities.

We should also mind the Paleoasiatic bear cult, common for many ancient tribes, not just for Slavs.

For Slavic languages, there are two options.

First, we can use the ***бер*** as in ***берлога*** (a place for a bear to lay) and ***бирюк*** (more often used to describe a wolf, but we shall return to the mistaking wolves and bears for each other later), but that did not derive from the PIE root you have mentioned, or even less common and, in my opinion, rather disputable ***ком***.

Second, the Old Greek cognate is ***ἄρκτος*** (cf. the name of [Arcas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcas)) which is related to Fenno-Ugric ***karhu***, ***ohto*** and ***otso***, as well as the Armenian [***arjer***] and Iranian cognates (Persian ***خرس*** [xarsh] and Kurdish ***hirç*** and ***hurç***, Osetian ***арс*** [ars]).

Judging by the Fenno-Ugric parallels and exceptions from the [I.U.R.K. law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruki_sound_law#Exceptions_in_Slavic_languages) for Slavic languages, and also by the Iranian cognates, we have the initial [x], the following sound between [a] and [o], the [r] from retroflexive [d] and a final [s] with a shwa or two.

All these facts put together, we receive Х@р(ъ)съ [х@r(ъ)sъ]  => ***Хърсъ*** [хъr(ъ)sъ] (cf. Ukrainian [Khortytsa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khortytsia) - remember the mistaking wolves for bears?) who was most likely a [solar-bear deity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hors) than a loan from Persian theological system.

Comment: This comment seems to ignore the exceptions for the IURK law in Slavic languages and parallels with FU loans, as well as the fact that the Fenno-Baltic languages are not IE.

Comment: There is literally no RUKI in a word that has no /s/ in it.

Comment: There is literally helluva RUKI in a word having an s-sound corresponding to BF h and interdental (P?)IE th (as in English 'other'/'thug') in it.

Comment: Please show me the RUKI in <h₂ŕ̥tḱos>.

Comment: Again, the RUKI applies for Slavic forms and its cognates/loans in FU languages (t = th = Slavic s = FU t/th/h), not for a hypotetic PIE form.

Comment: RUKI cannot apply in a word that is lacking the PIE sibilant: the rule itself is an individual sound-law (with special Slavic exceptions, sure). There are no magical interdentals randomly appearing in words compared with Finno-Ugric loans from an Iranian language that had a dorsal fricative. For comparison, the Avestan cognate in "aršô" (stem in <-> "arša-") has no such fricative, clearly showing no such RUKI.

Comment: Your statement of 'magical interdentals randomly appearing' is just false. A lisping sibilant is still a sibilant. The phonetic correlations (t = th = Slavic s = FU t/th/h = Proto-European retroflexal [d]) had been clearly shown. The correlation between IE [s] and FU [h] had also been proven long time ago.

Comment: And what does the Iranian languages have to do with the cognates/loans between Slavic and FU languages (not to mention the spectrum from initial [x] in many west Iranian up to [š/r] in West Iranian, including the Ossetian sample w.h.i.c.h.  h.a.d. a.l.s.o. b.e.e.n. s.h.o.w.n. i.n. t.h.e. i.n.i.t.i.a.l. a.n.s.w.e.r?

Comment: Does the Slavic *bьrlogъ* ( from **bьrlati*, “to disturb, to burden”) have anything to do with the bear ("the brown one"), other than a popular etymology?